# Microsoft Edge doesn't display PDF in iFrame with src="data:application/pdf;..."

Tags: pdf, iframe, microsoft-edge

Why does edge not display the PDF in the iframe. I'm getting 0 errors, warning etc. Are there any new restrictions regarding PDFs in iframe or is the feature just not supported anymore?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pf9kxx?file=index.html

Examples in browser: Chrome, Firefox and **EDGE**
[image]

Minimal code:

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,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"></iframe>
```

Comment: Maybe read here: https://caniuse.com/#search=datauri. Although the comment "anymore" leads me to believe you believe it worked before.

Comment: I remember it to work, but maybe it never did... :(

Comment: guess it doesn't work, here is the ms article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc848897(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but I have been stuck on this for a while and I figured it out.

The issue is that Edge has a char limit for URIs. You have to turn your pdf into a blob first.

```
//Convert to blob
var byteCharacters = atob(response);
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
     byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });

//Convert blob into URL Object
blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

 //Set URL Object as iFrame src
 document.getElementById('iframe').src = blob;
```

This should actually work for all modern browsers, so no need for browser/feature check.